# How can i make a button on this virtual Keyboard disappeare after its clicked

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've made a virtual Keyboard in html and css and now I want to write a code in JavaScript that makes a button invisible after clicking it.
I've tried this code but it didn't work:

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("simple_button");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to show us that.

Comment: Also, you can create a test case using the button that looks like a file with `</>` in it.

Comment: Simple hint.. On button click use event handler, or if you use jquery use $(this) object to hide .

Answer (score 0):

As grooveplex explained in the comments it is hard to give you an answer without seeing all of your markup and css.  But I will give you a pass because it is your first time here. 
If you would like to hide a button once clicked you can simply add a click event listener to all of your buttons then add a class to the clicked button.  Then give that class whatever style you would like the button to have once clicked. You probably want to use visibility hidden as it will maintain the structure of your visual keyboard

```js
    // get all buttons
    var documentButtons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    // add an event listener to all buttons
    for (var i = documentButtons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        documentButtons[i].addEventListener('click', removeButton);
    }
    // create remove button function (cross browser)
    function removeButton(e) {
        //  define variables
        var name, arr;
        // define class name
        name = "hidden";
        // define where to add the class name
        arr = e.target.className.split(" ");
        // add the class name
        if (arr.indexOf(name) == -1) {
            e.target.className += " " + name;
        }
    }
```

```css
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<button>Button 3</button>
<button>Button 4</button>
<button>Button 5</button>
```